# On Sitecore form submit show pop up with yes or no button and clicking Yes save the form data

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a requirement where on `Sitecore form` submit, I have to show a pop up with Yes/No option. And  once I click Yes, it would call save the form data.

Note: we are already using Sitecore form. and `CSaveaction` is working fine. But now have to add a pop up on submit and from pop up call save action.

[image]

So please suggest how to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: You can achieve this by javascript click event, on yes button click trigger form submit button.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. can you tell me how to trigger Sitecore form Submit action from script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `custom Submit button` and binding the `JS event` on the `cshtml`.

The `csthml` will look like the one below, where you can bind the confirmation box by clicking on the button. You need to follow the blow code and remove the logic and put the confirmation logic before submitting.

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Constants
@model Sc.FormsCustomScripts.Models.CustomScriptButtonViewModel
 
@{
    var cssClass = Model.CssClass;
    if (Model.NavigationStep < 0)
    {
        var classes = Model.CssClass.Split(' ');
        if (!classes.Contains("cancel", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CssClass))
            {
                cssClass += " ";
            }
 
            cssClass += "cancel";
        }
    }
}
 
<input value="@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)" type="submit" class="@cssClass" name="@Html.Name(Model.ItemId)" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" />
@Html.Hidden(AttributeNames.NavigationButtons, Model.ItemId)
@Html.Hidden(Model.ItemId, Model.NavigationStep)
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        var $inputEl = $("input[name='@Html.Name(Model.ItemId)']");
        var $formEl = $inputEl.closest('form');
        if ($inputEl.length == 0 || $formEl.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        $inputEl.click(function () {
            $("input[type=submit]", $formEl).removeAttr("clicked");
            $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
        });
        @if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name != "shell")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.FormSubmitScript)) 
            { 
                <text>
                    $formEl.on("submit", function () {
                        if ($inputEl.attr('clicked')) {
                            @Html.Raw(Model.FormSubmitScript)
                        }
                    });
                </text>
            }
        }
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

To know more about the custom submit event, refer to this article.

https://smartsitecore.com/en/call-custom-javascript-on-sitecore-forms-submit/

Comment: Thank you Sumit. Seems helpful. I am gonna try this.

Comment: @RashmiRanjan Please accept the answer once you think, it works for you. So it will be a solution for everyone .  Thanks